WPF control doesn't update when property is changed
I am developing a WPF app for my final university project (thesis). One of the goals is to be able to dynamically change the language of the UI. I suppose that it is not a very good idea to do it the way I am trying as it requires a lot of code, but for the sake of learning, I will go through with it.
The idea is to bind text properties in the XAML to properties in the LanguageViewModel and when the user changes the current language from a dropdown menu, all strings in the UI should change to the chosen language. With the code bellow, the OnPropertyChanged method is executed, but the UI elements don't update and after a lot of debugging, I still don't have any clue why.
I'm currently experimenting with a single TextBlock control. I have placed it between comments to make it easier to find.
This is my MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="AdjustrixWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdjustrixWPF"
    xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:AdjustrixWPF.View.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" Height="650" Width="850" WindowStyle="None"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}">
<Grid Name="MainGrid"
      Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="75*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyle}">
        <TabItem Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <userControls:TabHeader DataContext="{Binding languageViewModel}"
                    Text="File" 
                                        IsMouseOver="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"
                                        IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TabHeaderStyle}"
                                        Height="20"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0 0 1 0"
                        Margin="5">
                    <Grid Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
                          Width="300"
                          x:Name="TabPanelGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=TabPanelGrid, Path=ActualHeight}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!-- =========================================================== -->
                            <!-- This is the control I am currently experimenting with-->
                            <TextBlock x:Name="AppearanceBlock"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTabPanel}"
                                       Text="{Binding languageViewModel.Appearance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                       Margin="0 0 0 3"/>
                            <!-- =========================================================== -->
                            <userControls:LabeledComboBox LabelText="Language"
                                                          ComboBoxItemsSource="{Binding languageViewModel.Languages}"
                                                          ComboBoxSelectedItem="{Binding languageViewModel.CurrentLanguage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                                          x:Name="LanguageBox"/>
                            <userControls:LabeledComboBox LabelText="Theme"
                                                          ComboBoxItemsSource="{Binding Path=themeViewModel.Themes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                          ComboBoxSelectedItem="{Binding Path=themeViewModel.SelectedTheme, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                          Grid.Row="2"
                                                          x:Name="ThemeBox"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <userControls:TabHeader Text="Data"
                                        IsMouseOver="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"
                                        IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TabHeaderStyle}"
                                        Height="20"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="_" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButtonStyle}" Name="Minimize" Click="Minimize_Click"/>
        <Button Content="" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButtonStyle}" Name="Restore" Click="Restore_Click"/>
        <Button Content="╳" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButtonStyle}" Name="Close" Click="Close_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

This is the code behind where the data context is being set:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
        MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new();
        this.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    }

This is the MainWindowViewModel:
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ThemeViewModel themeViewModel { get; set; }

    public LanguageViewModel languageViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        themeViewModel = new ThemeViewModel();
        languageViewModel = new LanguageViewModel();
    }
}

This is the language view model:
internal class StringEntry
{
    public string Bulgarian { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public StringEntry(string bg, string en)
    {
        Bulgarian = bg;
        English = en;
    }

    public string GetString(Language currentLanguage)
    {
        if (currentLanguage == Language.English)
        {
            return English;
        }
        return Bulgarian;
    }
}

public class LanguageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private StringEntry file = new("Файл", "File");
    private StringEntry data = new("Данни", "Data");
    private StringEntry appearance = new("Изглед", "Appearance");
    private Language currentLanguage;

    public LanguageViewModel()
    {
        File = file.GetString(currentLanguage);
        Data = data.GetString(currentLanguage);
        Appearance = appearance.GetString(currentLanguage);
        //todo: later load it from AppData/Local
        currentLanguage = Language.English;
    }

    public string CurrentLanguage
    {
        get
        {
            return currentLanguage.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            currentLanguage = Language.English.ToString() == value ? Language.English : Language.Bulgarian;
            File = Language.English == App.Language ? file.English : file.Bulgarian;
            Data = data.GetString(currentLanguage);
            Appearance = appearance.GetString(currentLanguage);
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(File));
        }
    }

    public string File
    {
        get { return file.GetString(currentLanguage); }
        set
        {
            _ = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Data
    {
        get { return data.GetString(currentLanguage); }
        set
        {
            _ = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Appearance
    {
        get { return appearance.GetString(currentLanguage); }
        set { _ = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

And this is the base view model class:
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string member = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(member, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(member));
    }
}

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

The setters of the File, Data and Appearance properties are all pointless. These properties should be read-only, i.e. only have the get { ... } part. Then you may call OnPropertyChanged(null) or OnPropertyChanged("") to explicitly notify about the change of all properties.

Yes, that is correct. But after fixing that, the issue persists.

A breakpoint in the CurrentLanguage setter is hit when you select a language in the ComboBox?

Yes, I removed the setters for the File, Data, and Appearance properties and added the required OnPropertyChanged calls inside the setter of CurrentLanguage. Just did a test, added a breakpoint in the setter of CurrentLanguage and it was hit.

And another breakpoint in the Appearance getter is subsequently not hit?

The breakpoint in the getter of Appearance is NOT hit. Perhaps for some reason, the UI doesn't know that it should get a new value? But I added OnPropertyChanged for Appearance in the setter of CurrentLanguage

Your OnPropertyChanged implementation is wrong, see the answer. As a note, setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the TextBlock.Text Binding is redundant. UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings. It has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event.

Your OnPropertyChanged implementation is wrong. Instead of the property name you must pass this as first argument to the Invoke method:
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}


Thank you so much!!
